# Saxon: convert xdmNode to org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: java, dom, xpath, saxon, xpath-2.0

I would like to convert a xdmNode to a dom Node. I have found the following partial solution:

```
Processor proc = new Processor(false);
XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();
Document doc = DocumentUtilities.createEventCountsTestDocument();
XdmNode xdmNode = proc.newDocumentBuilder().wrap(doc);

expression = "/caseFileModel/EventCount/EventCountEvents[EventCmmnId=\"_4cd9cdaabbd244548a32afcd4cf2e1c0\" and EventEventType=\"CREATE\"]/Timestamps/Date[last()]";
value = xpath.evaluate(expression, xdmNode);
XdmNode node = (XdmNode) value;
Node element = ((Node) node.getExternalNode());
System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
```

Where `createEventCountsTestDocument` generates a document based on the following XML:

```
<caseFileModel>
        </EventCountEvents>
        <EventCountEvents>
            <EventCmmnId>_8dbe1b3fa1a04787b2ef35d153d93ae5</EventCmmnId>
            <EventEventType>CREATE</EventEventType>
            <EventCount>1</EventCount>
            <Timestamps>
                <Date>2017-03-13T16:47:04Z</Date>
            </Timestamps>
        </EventCountEvents>
        <EventCountEvents>
            <EventCmmnId>_4cd9cdaabbd244548a32afcd4cf2e1c0</EventCmmnId>
            <EventEventType>CREATE</EventEventType>
            <EventCount>1</EventCount>
            <Timestamps>
                <Date>2017-03-13T16:47:04Z</Date>
            </Timestamps>
        </EventCountEvents>
    </EventCount>
</caseFileModel>
```

I get the correct output namely `2017-03-03T12:00:00Z` however `element` is a `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl` and not a `w3c.dom.Node`. This means when I call `element.getNodeValue()` it returns `null`. If I call `element.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()` it does return the correct value `2017-03-03T12:00:00Z`. So there seems to be something wrong but I can not find it. I would like to find a way to convert the `xdmNode` to a `w3c.dom.Node` and not to a `DeferredElementImpl`.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, the DOM https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68D080 defines the node value of element nodes to be null so you get the right result. `Node` is an interface implemented by `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl`, I am not sure what kind of result you want. If you want a class based object model then use JDOM or XOM in the Java world, DOM by definition provides interfaces to be implemented by classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several points here. I'm afraid it's quite a complicated story.

Saxon has two interfaces for representing nodes: a high-level interface, `XdmNode` and a lower-level interface, `NodeInfo`. An `XdmNode` is always a wrapper for a `NodeInfo`.

`NodeInfo` has quite a number of different implementations. There are two "native" implementations in Saxon, for the TinyTree and LinkedTree models respectively; there are also implementations that wrap external node models including DOM, JDOM, DOM4J, XOM, and AXIOM.

If the `XdmNode` that you are starting with is a wrapper around a `NodeInfo` that itself wraps a DOM `Node`, then you can get to the underlying DOM Node using `XdmNode.getExternalNode()`. The signature of this method returns `Object`: that's because the wrapped node might be DOM, or it might be JDOM, XOM or whatever.

The above paragraph describes what you are currently doing. You don't need to worry that the result is an instance of `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl`; that's just one of the many internal classes that implements the `org.w3c.dom.Node` interface.

If the `XdmNode` that you're starting from isn't a wrapper around a DOM `Node`, then you have two options:

1. You can wrap the underlying `NodeInfo` in an instance of the `NodeOverNodeInfo` class, which presents a DOM view of the underlying `NodeInfo` node. However, this is a read-only view, because Saxon nodes (in general) are immutable.
2. You can copy the Saxon node to a DOM node, which is best done with an identity transformation.

In all of this you should be aware that Saxon, when processing DOM trees, is typically 5 times slower than when processing its own internal tree model. Most of this is due to the inefficient way that names and namespaces are handled in DOM.

Also, as you've discovered, the DOM methods for things like element.getNodeValue() don't always do what you might expect. Personally I avoid DOM like the plague.